# AWS EC2 instance, enable swap disk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

As the question suggests, is it a good recommendation to enable a swap file on an Amazon EC2 instance e.g T3.nano or T3.micro

Or should you solely rely on physical RAM?

Cheers

Comment: I use swap on my lightly loaded t2.nano, it works fine. If you swap to network disk a lot (EBS) it will probably get pretty slow. I have a lightly loaded t2.micro running Windows10 that gets into swap and is ok. In general, if you need the memory it's best to have RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paging space is useful when you are uncertain about maximum memory use and do not want to allocate more memory to hosts. This is your decision specific to your workload, you must do your capacity planning.

Local disks, where available, make good paging space, as durability and shared storage is not required.